# why is __init__ module in django project loaded twice

Tags: python, django

I put

```
print 'Hello world!'
```

into `__init__.py` in my django project. When I run `./manage.py runserver` now, I get

```
gruszczy@gruszczy-laptop:~/Programy/project$ ./manage.py runserver
Hello world!
Hello world!
Validating models...
0 errors found
```

Why is `__init__.py` run twice? It should be loaded only once.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It should be loaded only once... *per process*. I'm guessing that `manage.py` forks, and that two separate processes are launched. Could you print the result of `os.getpid()`?

Comment: Right.  Django uses two process for the reloading feature (ie. restart on code change),  if you run `./manage.py runserver --noreload` you get only one process.

Comment: If you check system timezone with `os.system('date +%Z')`, the first time it is your local timezone. The second time it is UTC, assuming that you have `TIMEZONE='UTC'` in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 5):

After learning the --noreload option from the above answer, I found that both

```
% django-admin help runserver
% manage.py help runserver
```

map to the below code in django/core/management/commands/runserver.py

```
parser.add_argument(
    '--noreload', action='store_false', dest='use_reloader',
    help='Tells Django to NOT use the auto-reloader.',
)
```

Both django-admin.py and manage.py call

```
django.core.management.execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I then started to trace the Django code to better understand why the two PIDs when --noreload is not given.

In below, we have

```
class BaseCommand defined in management/base.py and 
class Command(BaseCommand) defined in management/commands/runserver.py

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) ==>> utility.execute() ==>>
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv) ==>>
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options) in management/base.py ==>>
        super().execute(*args, **options) in commands/runserver.py ==>>
    output = self.handle(*args, **options) in base.py ==>>
        self.run(**options) in commands/runserver.py  ==>>
    if use_reloader:
        autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
    else:
        self.inner_run(None, **options)  // --noreload


    ParentPID run_with_reloader() ==>> DJANGO_AUTORELOAD_ENV = None ==>> 
    restart_with_reloader() only runs the 1st time by PPID ==>>
    ==>> subprocess.call(DJANGO_AUTORELOAD_ENV = true) ==>> child process cPID
    cPID run_with_reloader() ==>> "Watching for file changes with StatReloader"
    ==>> start_django(StatReloader, Command.inner_run) ==>>
    django_main_thread = threading.Thread(target=inner_run) and
    StatReloader.run(django_main_thread)
    ==>> Performing system checks... Starting development server at
    http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    The StatReloader(BaseReloader) will check file changes once per second.
    If there is a a file write => notify_file_changed(timestamp delta) =>
    trigger_reload() and PPID will spawn a new cPID and the old cPID is gone 
    so that we don't have to restart the runserver whenever there is a code change.
```

With the --noreload option, PPID executes inner_run() directly and skips the cPID subprocess for auto-reloading. If you kill either PPID or cPID, the whole process dies.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of finding out would be to raise an exception. Perhaps something like this in your **init**.py:

```
import os
if os.path.isfile('/tmp/once.log'):
    raise Exception
open('/tmp/once.log','w').write('first time')
```

Then you can inspect the traceback.

Comment: I like this approach but it only prints 'exited with code 1' for my traceback