# Why does django run everything twice?

Tags: django

Whenever I put in a (random) `print` statement in somewhere like `settings.py` or any random `.py` file in django, it gets printed twice. Why?

Try this:

after setting the value on `TEMPLATE_DIRS` (in `settings.py`), just add a print statement after it:
`print TEMPLATE_DIRS`

and you will get your templates directory printed out twice. Or if you're feeling old-fashioned, just add `print "Hello World` right after declaring `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, and it will print it twice.

Command to run : `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's not running it twice, it's forking to 2 processes and each one of those is running it once.

Answered by: [why is **init** module in django project loaded twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110545/why-is-init-module-in-django-project-loaded-twice)

> It should be loaded only once... per process. I'm guessing that
>   manage.py forks, and that two separate processes are launched.

and [an article.](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/duplicitous_django_settings.html)

To verify this if you add this to your `settings.py`

```
import os
print(os.getpid())
```

It will print out 2 different process id numbers showing that it's spawned 2 processes.

You can read more about forking [on wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(operating_system))

This also seems a duplicate of:

[django - settings.py seems to load multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149730/django-settings-py-seems-to-load-multiple-times)

Comment: Still does not answer why.

Comment: it's forked @GamesBrainiac - 2 forks then it gets loaded and printed twice.

Comment: Sorry to sound really stupid here, but do you mean, by it gets "forked".

Comment: It creates 2 separate processes - if you were to include `import os` and then `print(os.getpid())` you would see 2 different numbers representing 2 different processes :-)

Comment: But the question remains: why is it forked? (Probable answer: because you didn't specify `--noreload`, so one process is there to process requests and the other to watch if you changed any code so it can respawn the first one.)

Comment: What I did to run a command only once on the settings file was create a function to check whether we are in the main process:




`import psutil`

`def is_main_process():`

`current_process = psutil.Process()`

`parent = psutil.Process(current_process.ppid())`

`return parent.name() in ['bash', 'sh']`

then call it
`if is_main_process():  do_something()`