# Django settings.py statement executed twice

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my `settings.py` file and when I startup my server, the print statement gets called twice.   Why is that?

**settings.py**

```
if os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT'):
    print('Development Mode')
    DEBUG = True
    ADMIN_ENABLED = True
```

**Console**

```
Development Mode
Development Mode
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 16, 2020 - 20:34:23
Django version 3.0.8, using settings 'MyApp.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: I can confirm this behavior - would also like to know why.

Comment: Does this clarify the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149730/django-settings-py-seems-to-load-multiple-times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2110584/1730167

> If you run `./manage.py runserver --noreload` it should stop that from happening. Django uses two processes for the reloading feature hence why you are getting the double printing.