# Django Signals: How to initialize bindings?

Tags: python, django

I'm importing the signals file on the `__init__.py` file of the App. The issue happens when I run manage.py runserver i found that the `__init__.py` is imported two times, and my callbacks run two times.

But, when I run manage.py shell, the `__init__.py` it's worked as expected (one time)

(Django 1.8.3)

`app/__init__.py`:

```
print 'Hello!'
import signals
```

app/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class RemoteTask(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class RemoteTaskStatus(models.Model):
    remote_task = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField()
```

app/signals.py:

```
print '------> app/signals.py'

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from app.models import RemoteTask, RemoteTaskStatus

@receiver(post_save, sender=RemoteTask)
def status_new(sender, **kwargs):
    print '---------> Running callback'
    if kwargs.get('created', 'False') is True:
        instance = kwargs['instance']
        RemoteTaskStatus.objects.create(
            remote_task=instance,
            status=0
        )
```

Example output:

```
$ ./manage.py runserver
Hello!
------> app/signals.py
Hello!
------> app/signals.py
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 12, 2015 - 19:50:38
Django version 1.8.3, using settings 'signal_loca.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Solution from Angel Velasquez:
`app/__init__.py`:

```
print 'Hello!'
import app.signals
```

Comment: You may be interested in "Preventing duplicate signals": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is \_\_init\_\_ module in django project loaded twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110545/why-is-init-module-in-django-project-loaded-twice)

Comment: Thanks, but these links does not contribute to the solution

Comment: if I try your solution then I get the following error: "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet." How did you solve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Import your `signals.py` inside of an `AppConfig.ready` method to prevent the callback from being registered twice. Here's the recommended way to do this:

```
my_awesome_project/
|-- app/
|   |-- __init__.py   <-- set default_app_config here
|   |-- apps.py       <-- define your AppConfig subclass here
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- signals.py    <-- define your signal handling functions here
|-- other_app/
|-- my_awesome_project/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- settings.py
    |-- wsgi.py
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'app.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

**app/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name="app"

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

**apps/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class RemoteTask(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class RemoteTaskStatus(models.Model):
    remote_task = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField()
```

**app/signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from app.models import RemoteTask, RemoteTaskStatus

@receiver(post_save, sender=RemoteTask, dispatch_uid="status_new_signal_on_RemoteTask_post_save")
def status_new(sender, **kwargs):
    print '---------> Running callback'
    if kwargs.get('created', 'False') is True:
        instance = kwargs['instance']
        RemoteTaskStatus.objects.create(
            remote_task=instance,
            status=0
        )
```

**Edit:**

Added `dispatch_uid` to `receiver` decorator.

Comment: Thanks @chucksmash but I get the some issue with this.

Comment: @nachopro Your print statement in signals.py is outside of the if statement checking whether `instance` is being created or updated. Do you still see it twice if you move `print '---------> Running callback'` inside of the `if` block?

Comment: Yes chucksmash, when I run the tests (fails because when one RemoteTask is created, two RemoteTaskStatus are added) I got two prints "Running callback"

Comment: @nachopro in that case you can pass a `dispatch_uid` parameter to the `receiver` decorator.

Comment: :( Why Django, WHY?!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I've read that you were running tests? by any chance were py.test ? try deleting .pyc files or the `__pycache__` folder.

Comment: try:

import app.signals in your `__init__.py`