# In Django, what are the best ways to handle scheduled jobs where only one job is spun up instead of multiple?

Tags: python, django, multiple-instances, apscheduler

**[TLDR]** What are the best ways to handle scheduled jobs in development where only one job is spun up instead of two? Do you use the 'noreload' option? Do you test to see if a file is locked and then stop the second instance of the job if it is? Are there better alternatives?

**[Context]**
*[edit] We are still in a development environment and am looking to next steps for a production environment.*

My team and I are currently developing a Django project, Django 1.9 with Python 3.5. We just discovered that Django spins up two instances of itself to allow for real time code changes.

APScheduler 3.1.0 is being used to schedule a DB ping every few minutes to see if there is new data for us to process. However, when Django spins up, we noticed that we were pinging twice and that there were two instances of our functions running. We tried to shut down the second job through APS but as they are in two different processes, APS is unable to see the other job.

After researching this, we discovered the 'noreload' option and another suggestion to test if a file has been locked.

The noreload prevents Django from spinning up the second instance. This solution works but feels weird. We haven't come across any documentation or guides that suggest that this is something that you want to/not do in production.

Filelock 2.0.6 is another option that we have tested. In this solution, the two scheduled tasks ping a local file to see if it is locked. If it isn't locked, then that task will lock it and run while the other one will stop running. If the task crashes, then the locked file will remain locked until a server restart. This feels like a hack.

In a production environment, are these good solutions? Are there other alternatives that we should look at for handling scheduled tasks that are better for this? Are there cons to either of these solutions that we haven't thought of?

'noreload' - is this something that is done normally in a production environment?

Comment: Does this happen in `DEBUG = False` ?

Comment: All of this is terribly confusing. When you say "django spins up two instances of itself" what is the context? Are you running a management command? Are you running WSGI? Are you running Celery worker?

Judging from you use of --noreload, I suspect that you are trying to use a development django server. Well, this is a development server. It is not intended for use in production.

Comment: It seems like you are using `python manage.py runserver`. In production, you are supposed to use a real server such as Apache or nginx. This problem should go away without `runserver`

Comment: @MadWombat Sorry for the confusion. Based on the response from this, there is a suggestion to use the noreload to address multiple instances this. We are still in development but are now starting to look at a production environment.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2110584/4119116

Comment: Looks like you are running `runserver` from the command prompt. Don't do that for production. [Read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) for running on Apache.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan, yes this happens while Debug is set to false. Updating blurb.

Comment: Web servers are multi-threaded by nature. If you really need something to run only once, you should either implement it as a singleton or maybe re-evaluate your use of a web server in the first place. 

Running a scheduler from inside a django app is not a good idea. You might be able to hack the dev server into running only one thread, but you actually want multiple threads in production. Consider writing a stand-alone script for your scheduler.