# Paho-Mqtt django, on_message() function runs twice

Tags: python, django, mqtt, postgresql-9.3

I am using paho-mqtt in django to recieve messages. Everything works fine. But the on_message() function is executed twice.

I tried Debugging, but it seems like the function is called once, but the database insertion is happening twice, the printing of message is happening twice, everything within the on_message() function is happening twice, and my data is inserted twice for each publish.

I doubted it is happening in a parallel thread, and installed a celery redis backend to queue the insertion and avoid duplicate insertions. but still the data is being inserted twice.

I also tried locking the variables, to avoid problems in parallel threading, but still the data is inserted twice.

I am using Postgres DB

How do I solve this issue? I want the on_message() function to execute only once for each publish

my **init**.py

```
from . import mqtt  
mqtt.client.loop_start()
```

my mqtt.py

```
import ast
import json

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


# Broker CONNACK response
from datetime import datetime

from raven.utils import logger

from kctsmarttransport import settings


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    # Subcribing to topic and recoonect for
    client.subscribe("data/gpsdata/server/#")
    print 'subscribed to data/gpsdata/server/#'


# Receive message

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    # from kctsmarttransport.celery import bus_position_insert_task
    # bus_position_insert_task.delay(msg.payload)
    from Transport.models import BusPosition
    from Transport.models import Student, SpeedWarningLog, Bus
    from Transport.models import Location
    from Transport.models import IdleTimeLog
    from pytz import timezone
    try:
        dumpData = json.dumps(msg.payload)
        rawGpsData = json.loads(dumpData)
        jsonGps = ast.literal_eval(rawGpsData)
        bus = Bus.objects.get(bus_no=jsonGps['Busno'])
        student = None
        stop = None
        if jsonGps['card'] is not False:
            try:
                student = Student.objects.get(rfid_value=jsonGps['UID'])
            except Student.DoesNotExist:
                student = None
        if 'stop_id' in jsonGps:
            stop = Location.objects.get(pk=jsonGps['stop_id'])

        dates = datetime.strptime(jsonGps['Date&Time'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        tz = timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
        dates = tz.localize(dates)
        lat = float(jsonGps['Latitude'])
        lng = float(jsonGps['Longitude'])
        speed = float(jsonGps['speed'])

        # print msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload)
        busPosition = BusPosition.objects.filter(bus=bus, created_at=dates,
                                                 lat=lat,
                                                 lng=lng,
                                                 speed=speed,
                                                 geofence=stop,
                                                 student=student)
        if busPosition.count() == 0:
            busPosition = BusPosition.objects.create(bus=bus, created_at=dates,
                                                     lat=lat,
                                                     lng=lng,
                                                     speed=speed,
                                                     geofence=stop,
                                                     student=student)
            if speed > 60:
                SpeedWarningLog.objects.create(bus=busPosition.bus, speed=busPosition.speed,
                                               lat=lat, lng=lng, created_at=dates)
                sendSMS(settings.TRANSPORT_OFFICER_NUMBER, jsonGps['Busno'], jsonGps['speed'])
            if speed <= 2:
                try:
                    old_entry_query = IdleTimeLog.objects.filter(bus=bus, done=False).order_by('idle_start_time')
                    if old_entry_query.count() > 0:
                        old_entry = old_entry_query.reverse()[0]
                        old_entry.idle_end_time = dates
                        old_entry.save()
                    else:
                        new_entry = IdleTimeLog.objects.create(bus=bus, idle_start_time=dates, lat=lat, lng=lng)
                except IdleTimeLog.DoesNotExist:
                    new_entry = IdleTimeLog.objects.create(bus=bus, idle_start_time=dates, lat=lat, lng=lng)
            else:
                try:
                    old_entry_query = IdleTimeLog.objects.filter(bus=bus, done=False).order_by('idle_start_time')
                    if old_entry_query.count() > 0:
                        old_entry = old_entry_query.reverse()[0]
                        old_entry.idle_end_time = dates
                        old_entry.done = True
                        old_entry.save()
                except IdleTimeLog.DoesNotExist:
                    pass
    except Exception, e:
        logger.error(e.message, exc_info=True)


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("10.1.75.106", 1883, 60)
```

Comment: The only thing I know is that you are running 2 times the script, not the funcion, do you actually find a solution 2 this? I have the same issue

Comment: It looks like init is getting called twice.  Someone said Django has two processes, the main one, and the auto update one for live changes.  If you get the process ID (import OS os.getpid) you'll see two different process. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110545/why-is-init-module-in-django-project-loaded-twice . Use the --noreload flag to only load the one process.

Comment: @JavierCampos I actually ended up putting a unique constraint on the DB, to avoid duplicate data entry. So when i try to save the same object, the db throws the error, I capture that and reject the message. 

It is not the most efficient, but that hack solved the issue for that time being.

I am still yet to test the --noreload flag. I think that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some one mentioned in the comments run your server using --noreload

eg: python manage.py runserver --noreload

(posted here for better visibility.)

Comment: This method only works in local. The problem remain the same on heroku production enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!

Try using:

```
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    client.loop_stop(force=False)
    if rc != 0:
        print("Unexpected disconnection.")
    else:
        print("Disconnected")
```

Comment: Warnign: if your broker down, your client do not reconnect!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to execute your mqtt.py file from wsgi.py so you dont have to use --noreload

Comment: This method only works in local. The problem remain the same on heroku production enviroment.